# Model is not learning when using transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, transfer-learning

I am a beginner in machine learning and I am trying to develop a model that can predict age from a face dataset. However, my model is not learning and I am struggling to figure out why. I am importing the VGG16 architecture and it is still not learning. I have searched through forums and even tried training the model on only 2 examples and it is still unable to overfit.
Training accuracy barely increases and validation accuracy does not increase throughout training.

```
path = "../input/agedetection/dataset/dataset"
files = os.listdir(path)
X = []
age_temp = []

for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread(path+'/'+file)
    img = cv2.resize(img, dsize = target_size)
    X.append(img)
    fields = file.split('_')
    age_temp.append(fields[0])

X = np.array(X).astype('float32')
X = X/255

#converting age into different brackets  - 0-20, 21-40, 41-60,61+
age = np.zeros(len(age_temp))

for i in range(len(age_temp)):
    curr_age = int(age_temp[i])
    if curr_age <= 20:
        val = 0
    elif curr_age <= 40:
        val = 1
    elif curr_age <= 60:
        val = 2
    else:
        val = 3
    age[i] = val

age = to_categorical(age, num_classes = 4)
age = age.astype('float32')

base_model_age = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(input_shape=input_shape,include_top=False,weights="imagenet")
for layer in base_model_age.layers[:-20]:
    layer.trainable=False
model_age = Sequential()
model_age.add(base_model_age)
model_age.add(Flatten())
model_age.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model_age.add(Dense(4, activation = 'relu'))

model_age.compile(optimizer=Adam(adam),
              loss='mse'
              ,metrics=['accuracy'])

hist_age = model_age.fit(X_train, age_train,
                         validation_data=(X_validation, age_validation),
                         epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=256, 
                         callbacks=[lrd, mcp])
```

Comment: I'm not sure about why the model is not working, but here are a few notes that might be helpful. 1) You're leaving the last 20 layers of your network as trainable, I'm not sure why, I'm a bit rusty on VGG architecture but it seems to me that you'd be better off freezing the whole network since you're adding a dense layer. 2) You might want to experiment with increasing the epochs. 3) most importantly, mention how are you evaluating your network in your question, the error might be there. Finally, I don't see X_train and age_train definition in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You design the problem as a classification problem. However, your model is structured to be a regression one. If you do the following changes, you may get better predictions.

It seems like `model_age.add(base_model_age)` should be `model_age.add(base_model_age.output)`

Second, change

```
model_age.add(Dense(4, activation = 'relu'))
```

to:

```
model_age.add(Dense(4, activation = 'softmax'))
```

Third, change

```
model_age.compile(optimizer=Adam(adam),
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

to:

```
model_age.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Finally, you seem to train the last 20 layers. You may not have to train so many layers though, only top dense layers should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

And also make this change:

```
layer.trainable = True
```

Setting it to false will not train the parameters hence fine tuning will not happen.